# Solidworks - Copy equation driven linear pattern sketch to other plane

Tags: solidworks

**I am trying to create a 3d sketch similar to this (that is equation driven)**

[image]
(the image is a screenshot from a tutorial but the sketch in the tutorial is not equation driven unfortunately). image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBNAnqolQ-I (at 12:46)

**SW file:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VuQUzYxyjPer2lX7t0EAsDkeTctPBQJj

I made a sketch of a few points using a linear sketch pattern (amount of instances and spacing are both equation driven). The points that can be seen in the images below in my sketch will be used as the 'corners' of the 3d sketch .

If my explanation is unclear/incomplete please let me know and I'll try and fix it.

I want to have the same sketch on another parallel plane, I tried copying the sketch over to another plane but unfortunately when I change the equation variables the original linear sketch pattern sketch (on the original plane) does change (amount of instances/spacing) but the copied sketch (on the parallel plane) does not.

I also tried using 'convert entities' but unfortunately I cannot (or I don't know how to) select an entire sketch instead of individual points/lines/shapes etc using 'convert entities'. If I'm not able to select the entire sketch using 'convert entities' I am quite sure that when the number of instances of my original sketch changes the sketch on the second plane created using 'convert entities' will not have these instances added.

I could manually redraw the sketch (using the same equations/variables for the amount of instances in the linear sketch pattern and for the spacing in the linear sketch pattern) but I think there should be a better/more efficient way of doing it.

What am I doing wrong? What could be a possible solution to this issue?
Should I not use a loft for creating this model? is this the right approach?

**Some images:**

**First sketch drawn on original plane:**
[image]
 (the sketch = the 36-ish points on the line on the left side of the left plane in the image)

**Sketch copied over to second plane:**
[image]
This looks as if it has worked, however as soon as I change the variables in my equations the following happens (the original sketch's linear sketch pattern changes (the amount of instances/the spacing change) as they should according to the corresponding equations) but the copied sketch does not change at all.. which is an issue since I need all of the copies to change whenever I change the original.

[image]
[image]

background: I am trying to model DC motor windings using loft feature (as explained in the following post [How to model Motor Windings in Solidworks?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33361/how-to-model-motor-windings-in-solidworks)). I am trying to create the points required for the 3d sketch that can be seen in 'step 1' of the post I linked above.

**What I am trying to achieve:** (original sketch (in the green circle) to be copied over to the 3 lines (in the red circles) and all copies to change (number of instances/spacing) when i change the original sketch (by changing my equation variables).
[image]

**EDIT: I just thought of an issue with the approach explained above;** if I were to change the variables in my equations which would result in more points per sketch, the 3d sketch which i would draw by hand wouldn't get extra segments added automatically so i don't think it's a good approach.

Alternative approach (current plan of attack):

- 1) Draw 1 'spiral' (4 points) using 3d sketch (dimensions driven by equations/variables)
- 2) use loft feature to create solid body out of this sketch
- 3) linear pattern the loft feature (amount of instances in pattern and pattern spacing once again determined by variables/equations)

This way the model should update properly whenever the variables are changed in my equations and I won't have to do any manual fixing (I think). Any thoughts/suggestions/criticism regarding this approach? If so please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into sketch blocks?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I have not but I will, thanks for the suggestion